# How to animate Splatoon hair?

Tags: animation

I am struggling with the hair physics when working with models from Splatoon. I have tried both Soft Body and Wiggle Bones, but neither have produced a desireable result. The hair *does* have an armature

For reference, this is what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

Comment: you could also try cloth?

Comment: the cloth I've tried just makes it flat, what were you thinking?

Comment: you use cloth on an invisible plane, and you use this plane as the Object of a Surface Deform modifier you give to your hair

Comment: I'll try that and see how it works out

Comment: I'm going to give an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo of what you could try: Create your main object (1, head), the hair (2) that you subdivide as much as you want, and an invisible plane (3) that you subdivide a bit. Parent both the hair and the plane to the head. Give your head a *Physics > Collision*, give your plane a *Physics > Cloth* with a vertex group that you'll use as pin group (here the last edge on the left of the plane so that it sticks to the head). Give your hair object a *Surface Deform* modifier with the plane as *Target*, click on *Bind*:

[image]

Animate the head, the hair should move with the plane:

[image]

You can also use a cage and a *Mesh Deform* instead of a *Surface Deform* if needed:

[image]

Comment: I tried to do this, but all I got was the "hair" clipping through the "head" 
https://videoapi-muybridge.vimeocdn.com/animated-thumbnails/image/5956a1de-8472-4b84-a429-6c1e65effc24.gif?ClientID=vimeo-core-prod&Date=1624396055&Signature=1d9c86147500810e909378ebf7ebff32e4c13b48

Comment: I’m using blender 2.9

Comment: will i need to seperate the armature of my actual hair before doing this setup?

Comment: it looks like it's a question of Cache, delete the cache and choose the Disk Cache (you must have baked once, not sure why you need to click on Disk Cache though, then you can unclick)

Comment: that fixed the original object not using collision

Comment: could I simply dupe the hair object, then make it slightly bigger and use the cage method with that being my "simulation object"?

Comment: If you delete the cache, then enable and disable Disk Cache it should work. Not sure what you mean by "with that being my "simulation object""?

Comment: I mean, instead of a plane

Comment: you can try Mesh Deform and see what's the best