# Cloth simulation (to animate hair). The mesh breaks apart

Tags: cloth-simulation, hair

I have anime style hair which I am animating by using the cloth simulator.  I've pinned the top part of the hair which stays where it needs to be but the bangs just break up and fall to the floor.  I've searched for a way to stop this but can't find one anywhere.  I'm using Blender 2.93

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/228383/2214

Answer (score 4):

Ok here is my very personal way to solve this

- after drawing your hairs you need to check "fill caps" in spline shape
- then convert your hairs to mesh with good resolution for simulation
- Hit tab button and hit "a" button to select all your hair and hit "m" and by distance , and hit "Shift + n"
- create a vertex group and select vertexes inside skin or head which you not need to move and assign to vertex group
- add a hook modifier and choose the vertex group and the head ( or the bone related to head)
- in the physics properties choose cloth and in "shape" tap and in  pin group choose vertex group
- try to play with collision and self collision parameters (mostly reducing distance) and adding pressure (with custom volume) to achieve your desired results .
  [image]

Comment: That's brilliant!  Thank you :-)

Comment: @Karmalution you're welcome , if it was useful for you please accept the answer before some looters remove it .